# Is there an efficient way in MIPS to store floating point numbers in a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: arrays, floating-point, mips

I'm trying to store a list of floating point numbers in a dynamic array using MIPS. The program prompts the user for the number of floats to enter, and then loops while receiving the input.

With integers I know how to do this, but I am having a hard time making it work with floats. Here's what I have right now.

This gets the number of floats to be entered and allocates the memory accordingly:

```
#get number of floats to be entered
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t0, $v0      #t0 is number of floats

#allocate the memory required
sll $a0, $v0, 2
li $v0, 9
syscall
```

This is the loop where I collect the floats:

```
move $t1, $zero #idx for loop
move $t2, $v0 #t2 is address of dynamic memory

loop:
    bge $t1, $t0, done #idx check 

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt #prompt user input
    syscall

    # read in and store int
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    sw $v0, 0($t2)

    addi $t1, $t1, 1   # ++idx
    addi $t2, $t2, 4   #add four to move to next memory location
    j loop

done:
```

The output here is just 0.0 for any float that gets entered, when it should be the user entered numbers. I assume I must be storing them wrong. Is there a better way to bring in the floats than this?

Comment: Is `v0` the register where the system call puts the result of a read? What system is this? What is the output if you print the number as soon as it is read?

Comment: v0 should be the variable that the system call puts the result in. This is MIPS, being run on the MARS simulator. In MARS you can see the registers value, and it doesn't appear to be storing the floats in v0 at all.

Comment: [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) is the name of an instruction set architecture. That is just the “hardware.” It needs software to do anything. [MARS](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/index.htm) is a simulator that, [per its documentation](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) provides some rudimentary operating-system-like services. Thus, the `syscall` services are part of MARS, not MIPS. As the answers note, `syscall` #6 returns a result in `f0`, not `v0`.

Comment: Ahh, got it, Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Floats and doubles are not in normal integer registers. They have their own registers `$f0..$f31`.

`syscall 6` (and `syscall 7` for doubles) returns theirs results in `$f0` (not `$v0`), while `syscall 2` and `syscall 3` that print float and doubles expect their argument in `$f12`.

Copying operands to and from float registers is not done with `lw`and `sw`. You must use instead:

- `lwc1` (Load Word to Coprocessor 1) `lwc1 ft, offset(base reg)`
- `ldc1` (Load Double to Coprocessor 1) `ldc1 ft, offset(base reg)`
- `swc1` (Store Word from Coprocessor 1) `swc1 ft, offset(base reg)`
- `sdc1` (Store Double to Coprocessor 1) `sdc1 ft, offset(base reg)`

So your code should be:

```
move $t1, $zero #idx for loop
move $t2, $v0 #t2 is address of dynamic memory

loop:
    bge $t1, $t0, done #idx check 

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt #prompt user input
    syscall

    # read in and store floats
    li $v0, 6
    syscall
    swc1 $f0, 0($t2)  # read float is in $f0 

    addi $t1, $t1, 1   # ++idx
    addi $t2, $t2, 4   #add four to move to next memory location
    j loop

done:
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating point values typically occupy registers $f0 through $f31, which are completely separate from $0 (AKA $zero) through $31 (AKA $ra).

You load and store those floating-point registers using the lwc1/swc1 (for single precision) and ldc1/sdc1 (for double precision) instructions. This is very similar to using the lw/sw instructions.

Note also that the floating point registers are 32-bit on classical MIPS processors and so double precision values occupy adjacent registers (that is, you may have no more than 16 double precision values in the floating point registers at any given time). When using ldc1/sdc1 (and any floating point arithmetic instruction) for double precision you specify the even-numbered one ($f0, $f2, ..., $f30), and the next one ($f1, $f3, ..., $f31) is implicitly involved.